Why is there very little use of pointers as parameters in the standard library of Zig?
While reading some of the standard library source code, I have encountered very little use of pointers for function parameters, even with const, unless that specific parameter is edited by the function. From my perspective, it doesn't seem very efficient as you are making a complete copy of the argument (obviously a shallow copy). So why is this? Is it better than passing something as a constant pointer, or is it just the "idiomatic Zig way"?
Thank you very much.

in case you want to take a deep-dive, here's a talk related to the topic. At the moment (Zig is not 1.0 ...), it seems that you have to carefully watch out for what the compiler could do due to parameter reference optimization.

TL;DR if passed by value, the Zig compiler may still decide to pass by reference under the hood.
from the docs:

Primitive types such as Integers and Floats passed as parameters are
copied, and then the copy is available in the function body. This is
called "passing by value". Copying a primitive type is essentially
free and typically involves nothing more than setting a register.
Structs, unions, and arrays can sometimes be more efficiently passed
as a reference, since a copy could be arbitrarily expensive depending
on the size. When these types are passed as parameters, Zig may choose
to copy and pass by value, or pass by reference, whichever way Zig
decides will be faster. This is made possible, in part, by the fact
that parameters are immutable.

You can still pass by reference explicitly, and sometimes this is even necessary to prevent undefined behavior - for example in a struct's method, you could want to access data of that struct's instance, not a temporary copy of it which you would get from a pass-by-value. This can become a pitfall if your method returns a pointer.

So by passing by value, Zig can choose to pass it by reference, but is the opposite also true? I.e., if it is explicitly passed by reference, can Zig choose to pass it by value?
Finally, what do you recommend as a (I assume) frequent Zig user, a function to take parameters as values or as reference (obviously, if that parameter is not edited within the function, otherwise a reference would essentially be mandatory)?

@kupper is the opposite also true? - I think not. As noted, in some cases you must pass a reference, otherwise the functionality you're coding won't work. The compiler has to respect that. As for what I'd use, I guess I basically follow the std lib and would not explicitly specify pass-by-reference unless I have to. Like you I read a bunch of code and see what others do... It can cost you some nerves to find out what requires pass-by-reference, but the default (let the compiler decide) can avoid errors due to mutability of the data you're referencing (pointing to).

Yeah, seems like the best option. Thank you.
